# javascript increment index in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

I'm just trying to figure out how to create an index inside a function so I can keep track of the items its generating and I'm not sure how to do this seems like I should know this..

```
addLocation(options,location)

   funciton addLocation(options,location){
       $('#list').append('<li class="location"><div>'+location.label+'</div>'+
        '<input type="hidden" name="location['+x+'][lat]" value="'+location.lat+'" />'+
        '<input type="hidden" name="location['+x+'][lon]" value="'+location.lon+'" />'+
        '<input type="hidden" name="location['+x+'][loc]" value="'+location.loc+'" />'+
        '<input type="hidden" name="location['+x+'][label]" value="'+location.label+'" />'+
    '</li>');
   }
```

now normally you have a forloop to help you keep track of things but int this instance I'm not appending items in a loop and I keep getting an error saying x in undefined

appreciate any help you can give

thanks
Mike

Comment: What value(s) should x be in this example?

Comment: @Zack values should be an integer

@vicatcu i haven't defined x because I'm not sure how to  with out making x 0 all the time

Comment: @mcgrailm, do you mean that each time the function is called, `x` should be incremented?

Comment: @mcgrailm, clear enough now, I posted an answer...

Comment: @CMS not really I'm not sure how to call the function now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since what you want is that each time the function is called, `x` should be incremented, you can store `x` in a closure, for example:

```
var addLocation = (function (){
  var x = 0; // store x
  return function (options,location) {
    x++; // increment x
    $('#list').append('<li class="location"><div>'+location.label+'</div>'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="location['+x+'][lat]" value="'+location.lat+'" />'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="location['+x+'][lon]" value="'+location.lon+'" />'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="location['+x+'][loc]" value="'+location.loc+'" />'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="location['+x+'][label]" value="'+location.label+'" />'+
    '</li>');
  };
})();
```

Comment: so then I call the the function by variable ? how are the parameters gonna make it into the function sorry never seen this done before

Comment: just call `addLocation(options, location)`.  The anonymous function with no parameters is there for the closure, the inner function that takes two parameters is what gets assigned to `addLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare x since in your above code it's not defined.

```
var x = 0;
```

Comment: Well you will have to define it as something I just put 0 because I don't know what value you are trying to derive. What are you basing the index off of, looks like `zincorp` has the right idea of what to base the index off of.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $("#list>li").length + 1;
```

Comment: If the items get removed, this should still account for that as long as you are removing `<li>`'s

Comment: ok so lets say i have 4 li's x should be up to 3  then I add a fifth x goes to 4 i remove li3  and my x remains at 4